# import custom class in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 custom PHP classes placed in Lib folder. In Controller I need to import following class `Custom2`, which is inporting class `Custom`. I can use class `Custom2` by instantiation this class and invoking its method inside Controller`s action as following:

```
<?php
App::import('Lib', 'custom2');
class TestController extends AppController {

    function index() {
         $custom = new Custom2();
         $test = $custom->test();
    }

}

?>
```

But problem is, that including `Custom.php` inside `Custom2.php` is not working trough `include_once`. I am using this implementation:

```
Custom2.php:

<?php
include_once 'Custom.php';

class Custom2 {
    public function test() {
         $test = new Custom(); // this is not working               
    }
}
?>
Custom.php:

<?php

class Custom {
    public function test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
?>
```

Both classes are in the same folder(Lib). What is wrong here?

Comment: Apparently you may either put them in a package and use it, or place them in a vendor subdir, and import that: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put them in the `Vendor` folder, as described in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files).

```
App::import('Vendor', 'custom2');
```

Another option would be to put in the `Lib` folder

Comment: But how can I include Custom.php inside Custom2.php?

Comment: you can use `include_once`

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. Now it looks like edited post above.